# How do I ensure my Java Play application only accepts HTTP requests from a particular host?

Tags: java, security, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm using the [Play framework for Java](https://www.playframework.com/) for an app. I am attempting to make it distributed by deploying copies of the application across several servers and having a configurable list of nodes in the database, which must be able to communicate between each other. In MongoDB, the list is stored in JSON like so:

```
{
  "master": "host1.com:2678",
  "nodes": ["host2.com:2678", "host3.com:2678", "host4.com:2678"]
}
```

The code deployed on each server is identical, but the scheduler is enabled only on the master node and will schedule particular work to nodes depending on how busy they are. Code not provided here as the specifics of the scheduler's operation isn't important for my question.

In order to know how busy they are, to schedule things and for other status updates, the nodes need to be able to communicate with each other.
Play Framework's [Web Service client](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaWS) allows me to do this by making HTTP requests from within one node to the other like so

```
HttpResponse res = WS.url("http://host2.com").get();
```

But the idea is for specific HTTP requests (such as those used for scheduling) to be allowed only if coming from another one of the nodes (Be it the master or slave nodes) but not from a web browser, curl, etc. How do I do that securely? I can check for the host of the incoming request or particular headers but surely those are easy to forge?

Answer (score 2):

If you want this to be enforced on all controllers, Check out play allowed hosts [filter](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/AllowedHostsFilter).

If you want to enforce this filter on a specific Controller \ method you can try to do this:

```
class MyController @Injects()(filter: AllowedHostsFilter) extends Controller {
  def get = filter.apply(Action.async { implicit request =>
    Future.successful(Ok)
  })
}
```

Comment: They apply a blanked filter though on all HTTP requests. Is there a way to only apply that to particular controllers?

Comment: @SamuilDichev I updated my answer. hope it helps you.

Comment: That definitely looks like it might be what I'm looking for. Is there, however, a chance that you show me how this is done in Java? I'm not sure I fully understand what you're doing with that code.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look into [pac4j.org](http://www.pac4j.org/index.html) they have a lot of options to implement security features on play.

You could maybe filter by ip address:

http://www.pac4j.org/1.9.x/docs/authenticators/ip.html